# Manga where the protagonist us transported to another world and tortured, after which he escapes and meets a fairy

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I read this mange quite a few years ago.

The protagonist was transported to another world and tortured by his summoners. He was then forced into combat with other prisoners, however he gains black magic and when the opportune moment arrives, he escapes. He runs into a fairy; the fairy is hated because she is half human or something. The two end up having an odd relationship; I don't know if they end up loving each other because it was still ongoing when I read it. The protagonist later goes to a city and runs into a girl being attacked; the girl turns out to be testing the protagonist.

If anyone can help me find this book it would be a great help; it's one of those stories that broke from the normal isekai and I rather enjoyed it. The title had something like the (Black Devil) or (Black King) maybe (Evil King). What I do know is that it was a long title.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this? Also, was it in full colour or mostly black & white?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for *Kuro no Maou* by Hishikage Dairi and Matoba Ryou which was first written as a web novel with the same name and then adapted as a manga.

> Kurono Maou is a high school student who is sensitive of his sharp eyes and bad expression. No girlfriend but gifted with friends in his own way, he had been living a peaceful life. But one day, without any reason, Kurono was attacked by a mysterious headache while in the literature clubroom and fainted. When he finally awoke.......Swords & magic, filled with monsters, an orthodox different world summoning.

> The protagonist was transported to another world and tortured by his summoners.

[image: The character being tortured]

> He was then forced into combat with other prisoners, however he gains black magic

[image: The character discovering his black magic]

> He runs into a fairy; the fairy is hated because she is half human or something.

[image: The character meeting the fairy]